# why is the length of arc in polar coordinate like this?

Tags: polar-coordinates, arc-length

I learned $L=\int_a^b{\sqrt{r^2+\frac{dr}{d\theta}^2}d\theta}.$ But, Why do I calculate like $L=\int_a^b{rd\theta}$ ?
In my opinion, considering riemann sum like $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}{r(\theta_i)\triangledown\theta}}$  is better because the formula of arc in circle is $L=r\theta$.
Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Yes, the arc of a circle *around the origin* is measured by $r \Delta \theta$ in polar coordinates, so in that case $L=\int_a^b{rd\theta}$ will work fine. But of course in that case $dr/d\theta = 0$ so the two formulas are equivalent. Why would you expect a formula that works *for a circle centered on the origin* to work for any other curve? What is your question, really?

Comment: Yes . I expect a formula to work for any other curve. Why not? I think that Riemann sum consider all their elements start from origin.

Comment: Well, I have a formula $\int_a^b dx$ that perfectly describes the length of a horizontal line in Cartesian coordinates. So why shouldn't it work just as well for any other curve, for example the straight line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,9)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exercise to test your formula.

Consider the straight line from polar coordinates $r=\sqrt2,\theta=\frac\pi4$
to polar coordinates $r=1,\theta=\frac\pi2.$
You may recognize this as the line segment from $(1,1)$ to $(0,1)$ in Cartesian coordinates. The length of the curve is $1.$

The polar equation of the line through these points is $r = \dfrac{1}{\sin\theta}.$

So according to your formula we should calculate the length of the line as
$$
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\, \mathrm d\theta \approx 0.8814.
$$

To make a Riemann sum for the length of a curve in polar coordinates you can
draw many rays from the origin intersecting your curve, including a ray through the start of the curve and one through the end, so that you partition the curve into smaller pieces. So far, this is a correct approach.
The formula you have given is equivalent to the assumption that the length of each piece of the curve under this partition is approximately $r \Delta \theta$ where $r$ is somewhere between the minimum and maximum distance from the origin along that part of the curve and $\Delta \theta$ is the angle between the rays.
This assumption is not a terrible one when $\mathrm dr/\mathrm d\theta$ is small,
but it works very poorly when $\mathrm dr/\mathrm d\theta$ is large.
Even for the example above, where $\mathrm dr/\mathrm d\theta = -\sqrt2$
at one end of the segment, you have a substantial overall error.

It is fundamentally the same mistake you would make by assuming that the length of the part of a curve between two vertical lines in Cartesian coordinates is simply the distance between the lines.

Comment: so, It means that when I assume $r(\theta)$ represents $\theta \in [a,b]$, $r(\theta)$ must not change dramatically?

Comment: It means if you want to use $\int_a^b r\,\mathrm d\theta$ as an exact mathematical expression for curve length, $r(\theta)$ must not change **at all**. If you're willing to tolerate some fraction of a percent error then a little variation in $r(\theta)$ is OK, but it must be small relative to the length of the curve and not too rapid. (Even if you just have $r = 1 + \sin(1000\theta)/1000$, so that $0.999\leq r\leq1.001,$ it is a lot of extra length.)

Comment: I think proving a correct measurement of the length of a curve is a very hard thing to do. Much harder than measuring the area of a figure in a plane via calculus, for example. I can show what is wrong with some ways to do it but to prove that the accepted formulas are really and truly correct is much harder.

Comment: So, the reason that the common formula of length is $L=\int_a^b{\sqrt{r^2+\frac{dr}{d\theta}}d\theta}$ is $s^2=x^2+y^2$ is identity?

Comment: Yes, it is basically the Pythagorean Theorem. It's just that with the polar coordinate formulation you have to factor carefully to identify the lengths of the triangle sides in the formula. (And when you find them, they're only sides of a right triangle in the limit; in any finite partition you still have a little curvature in the "$r\Delta\theta$ side".)

Comment: thank you for kind answer!!

Answer (score 0):

normally people say:
$$dL=\sqrt{(dy)^2+(dx)^2}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+1}\,dx$$
using the fact that $y=r\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ work out $dy/dx$ and $dx$ to derive $dL$ then integrate.

Comment: I understood why this formula work. but I don't understand why above formula doesn't work..

Comment: they are not equal, there is no reason why it should work